# Can't mount SD card partition to /boot, but works elsewhere

Tags: boot, mount

I have a server (DL360p if that matters) that boots off the internal SD card slot. For some reason, the `/boot` filesystem failed after boot. I have pulled the SD card into my laptop and ran filesystem checks, all is fine, the files are there. I have since put the SD card back into the server slot, and it is successfully detected with no filesystem error.

I then tried to mount the partition on `/boot`, but it won't work. I can mount it elsewhere though, and the files are there (this snipped is done with `dmesg -w &`):

```
root@dikkenek:/# rmdir boot
root@dikkenek:/# mkdir boot
root@dikkenek:/# mount /dev/sde1 /boot
root@dikkenek:/# [4983170.551071] EXT4-fs (sde1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

root@dikkenek:/# ls boot
root@dikkenek:/#
```

Elsewhere:

```
root@dikkenek:/# mkdir boote
root@dikkenek:/# mount /dev/sde1 /boote
root@dikkenek:/# [4983211.174716] EXT4-fs (sde1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

root@dikkenek:/# ls boote
config-5.10.0-10-amd64  config-5.10.0-15-amd64  grub                        initrd.img-5.10.0-11-amd64  initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64  System.map-5.10.0-10-amd64  System.map-5.10.0-15-amd64  vmlinuz-5.10.0-10-amd64  vmlinuz-5.10.0-15-amd64
config-5.10.0-11-amd64  config-5.10.0-16-amd64  initrd.img-5.10.0-10-amd64  initrd.img-5.10.0-15-amd64  lost+found                  System.map-5.10.0-11-amd64  System.map-5.10.0-16-amd64  vmlinuz-5.10.0-11-amd64  vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64
root@dikkenek:/#
```

I have this line in my `/etc/fstab` and the UUID matches:

```
root@dikkenek:/# grep boot /etc/fstab
# /boot was on /dev/sde1 during installation
UUID=2ea55b27-d7d5-4e0d-8734-f69d92cb8407 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
root@dikkenek:/# blkid /dev/sde1
/dev/sde1: UUID="2ea55b27-d7d5-4e0d-8734-f69d92cb8407" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="fd5af08d-01"
```

`mount -a` doesn't fail but doesn't mount either.

How come it won't mount on `/boot`? I can't reboot now, or upgrade my kernel.

The server runs Debian 11 bullseye (Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64) if that matters.

Edit: another test:

```
root@dikkenek:/# mount --bind /boote /boot
root@dikkenek:/# ls boot
root@dikkenek:/# ls boote
config-5.10.0-10-amd64  config-5.10.0-15-amd64  grub                        initrd.img-5.10.0-11-amd64  initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64  System.map-5.10.0-10-amd64  System.map-5.10.0-15-amd64  vmlinuz-5.10.0-10-amd64  vmlinuz-5.10.0-15-amd64
config-5.10.0-11-amd64  config-5.10.0-16-amd64  initrd.img-5.10.0-10-amd64  initrd.img-5.10.0-15-amd64  lost+found                  System.map-5.10.0-11-amd64  System.map-5.10.0-16-amd64  vmlinuz-5.10.0-11-amd64  vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64
```

I'm afraid I'll have to reboot to fix this...??

Comment: try using absolute path for all commands

Comment: what happens if you do `rmdir boot` followed by  `ls boot`?

Comment: same with absolute paths. `rmdir boot; ls boot` yields no such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete apt updates by removing `/boot`, mounting `/dev/sde1` on `/boote` and then adding a symlink from `/boot` to it.

Apt didn't flinch, it could run grub updates and other system updates.
I'm going to assume that once the server reboots, whatever problem it had mounting will be gone, and I will be able to boot on the new kernel seamlessly.